# PHP OOP structure problem, simulate multiple inheritance

Tags: php, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have an e-shop with multiple product types. And i would have thought of the following structure

```
Cart_Item
-- Cart_Product
-- Cart_Download

Order_Item extends Cart_Item
-- Order_Product
-- Order_Download
```

The problem is that i want to have Order_Product extend Order_Item and Cart_Product.
This is because it needs method generic to Order_Item ( get price from Order not from product ) but also methods from Cart_Product ( shipping calculations )

I know that php doesn't support multiple inheritance, i was wandering what is the cleanest way to emulate this.

Right now i have Order_Product extend Cart_Product duplicate code from Order_Item in Order_Product an Order_Download.

Comment: @Gordon thank you for your answer, i used composition. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either use [Interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) and implement the methods manually or via [Strategies](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy). Or use [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead of Inheritance, meaning you let the `Order_Product` have a `Order_Item` and a `Cart_Product`.

<sup>On a sidenote: You could also consider making "shipping calculations" into it's own Service class that you can pass appropriate Product instances to.</sup>

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance, unless you have a very good reason not to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance