# How to extends multiple class

Tags: php

my application structure:

**E:\wamp\www\mobile\module\mod_expense.php** CLASS NAME: mod_expense Descrition : contains the INSERT,DELETE,UPATE Operation  and also this clas extends con_class CLASS

**E:\wamp\www\mobile\controller\contr_busniss.php** CLASS NAME: con_class Description: Contain the select query business logics

**E:\wamp\www\mobile\view\expenditure\expense.php**  Description: Contains the expense.html CLASS and contr_busniss.php CLASS Purpose: With this file Application running for example if want to display the Expense ADD FORM , then my URL looks likg **http://localhost/mobile/view/expenditure/expense.php?fp=add**
Expense VIEW FORM , then my URL looks likg http://localhost/mobile/view/expenditure/expense.php?fp=view

**E:\wamp\www\mobile\view\expenditure\expense.html.php**  CLASS NAME: expense_html_form Description: Contains the FORM (ADD Expense, Edit Expense, View Expense) and also this clas extends con_class CLASS

Now i have Database class: CLASS Name is DB_Class, i want to use these class functions in mod_expense.php & expense.html.php , i am not much femiliar with OOPS,

Currently these file are already extends the con_class CLASS, Now i want to extends the Database class, How to extend the DB CLASS Here,

Few my snippet here:

**File name : expense.php**

```
include("../../include/config.php");
include("../../include/dbclass.php");
include_once("expense.html.php");
include("../../controller/con_error.php");
include_once("mod_expense.php");
 $obj_dbclass = new dbClass();
 $obj_dbclass->db_connect();


 $expense_object = new expense_html_form();
 $expense_object->expense_add();
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $mod_expense = new mod_expense();
    echo $mod_expense->ins_expense();
 }
```

**File name : expense.html.php**

```
class expense_html_form{

    function expense_add(){
        ADD FORM
    }
}
```

**File Name: mod_expense.php**

```
class mod_expense extends con_class{
    function ins_expense(){
         EXPENSE ADD FUNCTIONALITY
    }
}
```

**File Name: contr_busniss.php**

```
class con_class{  

    function check_already_exist($amount){
echo "SELECT expense_amount FROM expense WHERE expense_amount = '$amount'";
        $select=mysql_query("SELECT count(expense_amount) FROM expense WHERE expense_amount = '$amount'");
                $row=mysql_fetch_array($select);
                $op=$row[0];
                return $op;
    }
}
```

Now i want extends the DBClass function. Advise how to  achieve.

Comment: simple how to achieve when we want to extend more than one class

Comment: PHP does not support multiple inheritance, if this is what you are looking for. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889080/php-oop-structure-problem-simulate-multiple-inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're trying to accomplish too much with inheritance when composition would be better for your situation. You could pass a reference to `$dbClass` to your controllers so they have access to database functionality.

From the names of your classes I assume that you're trying to use Model-View-Controller, in which case I would recommend against exposing the `DB_class` functionality to `expense_html_form`. You should instead perform any necessary calculations within your controllers and give the end result to the view.

If you absolutely must use inheritance, having `expense_html_form` and `con_class` extend `DB_class` would expose those methods to `expense_html_form` and `mod_expense`.